# How to inherit the properties of a member variable into the host class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

Imagine the following code:

```
class X(object):
    def geta(self):
        return self.__a

    def seta(self, v):
        self.__a = v

    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.__a = a

    a = property(geta, seta)

class Y(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.X = X(v)

    # !!! Here, not sure how to do it
    a = X.a


x = X(12)

print x.a
x.a = 2
print x.a

print "-" * 79

y = Y(2)

print y.a
```

Essentially, what I want is to have `class Y` inherit `class X`'s properties. So that `Y.a` will actually go to `Y.X.a`. So if I say: `y = Y(2)` and then `y.a = 2` it should be as if I did `y.X.a = 2`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I was not clear enough. Say X had a few more properties, say 'b', 'c' 'd' and 'f'. How can I directly map say attributes 'a', 'b' and 'f' into Y ?

Comment: Your X class looks like literally translated Java code.  Don't add setters and getters just to wrap access to a member variable.  Drop `seta`, `geta` and the `a` property, and just define `__init__` as `self.a = a`.  Unlike Java, there is no refactoring/rebuilding penalty if you decide later to make `a` into a property.  Also, go sparingly on the leading `__` attributes - stick with just leading `_` to indicate a "not intended for public access" member variable.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to Y:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return getattr(self.X, attr)
```

Now all unresolved attribute references to a Y instance will forward to its contained X.

Comment: hmm, better then to check if 'attr' == 'a' then return self.X otherwise consult the __dict__ huh?

Comment: Do you mean "check first ('consult the dict') to see if the named attribute is defined on Y before delegating to the contained X"?  Python does that already, and only calls `__getattr__` if attr is not defined on the Y instance.  Of course, if you only wanted to delegate to X for properties a, b, and z, then you would conditionalize this code, and raise AttributeError if some other property was given.

Comment: Also, there is no need for `try: return getattr(self.X, attr); except AttributeError: raise` or `if hasattr(self.X, attr): return getattr(self.X, attr); else: raise AttributeError()`  Python does all this work for you too, so there is no need to replicate (at the risk of introducing bugs) in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are inherited like any other attribute... if you actually inherit from the class. What's wrong with that?

```
class Y(X): pass
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah why not. I was not thinking of having Y inherit from X since  in my real life program they do not inheritance relationship.

Comment: It would help to explain the actual relationship, and the reason for wanting to inherit a property.

Comment: For this case, I can have them inherit from each other. But my question was not clear. Suppose Y had two attributes X which has 'a' and Z which has 'b' (and maybe even more other cases). I want to pick and choose a few attributes from Y's members and expose them. Currently, I would have to re-write get/set methods in Y and expose the properties manually again...I was hoping there is a syntax where I can directly have a property in Y map to a property in one of its children.

Comment: Or you could factor out a common base class? :s

Comment: Yes, that's a solution...but I was hoping there is a mapping syntax. Check my "HERE" marker in the code...obviously it is incorrect.

Comment: Inheritance adds greater coupling and dependency between classes. This approach of "containment and delegation" is a well-understood alternative to inheritance.